# Поймать ссылку в защищенном JS

Tags: javascript, php

Внимание, 18+!

Всем привет.
Делаем граббера для сайта, но столкнулись с проблемкой. Есть сайт-жертва https://hpjav.tv/142737/wanz-397 . При нажатии на кнопку VO Server под плеером идет подгрузка embed ссылки в iframe. Ссылка во фрейме вида https://vidoza.net/embed-7y8faotag.html
Ява там летает защищенная, поэтому простыми средствами PHP не получается вычленить эту ссылку.

Подскажите пожалуйста средства, благодаря которым можно это сделать. Желательно с подробностями. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вам необходимо смотреть в сторону безголовых (headless) браузеров, таких, как puppeteer, например.

Не знаю, что там, в php сейчас актуально по этой теме...
Можно глянуть на https://github.com/nesk/puphpeteer

А вот PhantomJS для php давно уже "мертвый", по-моему.

Скорей всего Вы остановитесь на https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver (Selenium)

Anyway, примерно так будет выглядеть решение на nodejs с использованием puppeteer:

```
    (async () => {
    
        //Запускаем безголовый браузер
        const browser = await BrowserLaunch({
            args: [],
            headless: false
        });
    
        const media = []; //Сюда складываем запросы с типом Медиа
    
        const page = await browser.newPage(); //Открываем новую страницу
    
        await page.goto('https://hpjav.tv/142737/wanz-397'); //Переходим на какой-то порно сайт
    
        await page.click('#btn3'); //Кликаем по VO SERVER
    
        await page.waitFor(5555); //Ждем 5 секунд
    
        //Получаем от страницы список подгруженных ресурсов
        const tree = await page._client.send('Page.getResourceTree');
        
        //Проходимся по списку. Записываем урл ресурсов с типом Медиа
        for (const resource of tree.frameTree.resources) {
            if (resource.type.toLowerCase() === 'media') {
                media.push(resource.url);
            }
        }
    
        console.log(media) //Вот все медиа ресурсы подгруженные
    
        await browser.close(); //Закрываем браузер
})()
```